# How to scroll on increasing picturebox size in windows form c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I have a PictureBox control in windows form with a movable rectangle drawing in it, my PictureBox size will increase according to the position of the rectangle, when the PictureBox size is greater than a particular size scrollbar will appear.

```
public void PicBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

       if (rect.Contains(new Point(e.X, e.Y)))
       {
           mMove = true;
       }

       oldX = e.X;
       oldY = e.Y;
}

 public void Picbox_MouseUp(object sender , MouseEventArgs e)
 {
      mMove = false;
 }

 public void Picbox_MouseMove(object sender,MouseEventArgs e)
 {
      if (mMove)
      {
            picBox.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
            rect.X = rect.X + e.X - oldX;
            rect.Y = rect.Y + e.Y - oldY;
      }
      oldX = e.X;
      oldY = e.Y;
      picBox.Invalidate();
 }

public void Picbox_MousePaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
        picBox.Invalidate();
        picBox.Size = new Size((rect.Width + rect.X) + 10, (rect.Height + rect.Y) + 10);
        Draw(e.Graphics);  
}
```

[image]

On first display of form with pictureBox

[image]
[image]

After dragging the rectangle the size of the pictureBox increases and scroll bar appears

everything works fine here but my problems is no matter how much the size of the pictureBox is the scroll bar works fine when i drag it down,but when the rectangle is dragged up and if the edges of the pictureBox meets the form the whole scroll bar is reset to normal, by looking at the pictures below you will be able to understand what i want to say

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to solve this, is there another way to increase scroll according to the width of pictureBox ? i am new at this.

the rectangle is acting as if the the X and Y co-ordinates are tracked with respect to winform but not pictureBox.

Can i make pictureBox as a parent for my Drawing?

Comment: Not sure what you want, but the usual way to get a scrolling PB is to put the  PictureBox inside a Panel with AutoCcroll=true for the Panel and false for the PictureBox.

Comment: the height of the picturebox will increase when i drag the rectangle vertically and i assign the postion and height of the Rectangle to the picturebox's size for example picturebox.Size = Rectangle.Height + Rectangle.Y so the height of the picturebox increases when i drag it down and scroll bar apperas but when i drag it up as you can see in the last image, when the picturbox is above the form edge the scroll bar is gone.

Comment: Is that what you have, and if so what is the question or is that what you want? - Also: What are  `Picbox_MousePaint`  and `Draw` ? Where is the dragging code?

Comment: _when the picturebox is above the form edge_ Is it? Where do you change the Top or Y value??

Comment: Yes when the picturebox is above the edge. i have updated the code,Draw method just draws the rectangle and nodes

Comment: Ah, you are right. Forms don't show Scrollbars when Controls are located in the negative. Do use a Panel for this, as I have suggested or make sure to keep Top and Left >= zero!

Comment: so if i add the picturebox inside the panel and if i drag it above the edge then the panel will still show the scroll?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76039/discussion-between-taw-and-user2208996).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't possible.

In `Winforms Scrollbars` will only bring things back into view that have **overflown** their container. If they 'underflow', ie if their `Top` and/or `Left` values get negative no `ScrollBars` show and even if they do (because of additional overflow) they won't bring them back.

The minimum scroll position is `zero`.

So you will have to make sure not to move things into the negative!

You can enforce `ScrollBars` by adding dummy controls but that will only allow you to completely scroll the `PictureBox` up or left out of sight, not back!

If you really really really really really really want to you can detect the situation and manually add `ScrollBar` controls and code them to move the `PictureBox` back down/right..

Since you were asking, here is an example to play with. Note though that working with [coded ScrollBars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.vscrollbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has numerous pitfalls..

- One of them would be how to handle the situation when the real `ScrollBar` shows up as well? In the example I solve it by not adding the ScrollBar to the Panel but by overlaying it; thus the real ScrollBar is hidden while the coded one is showing.
- Another problem are the numbers: How many pixels should the content be moved? I don't let the uses scroll anywhere but up and when that happens I move the PictureBox all the way back and the coded ScrollBar disappears..
- As a last point of warning it should be noted, that a coded `ScrollBar` lets you do things to the controls you have; but **it won't allow you to actually scroll into the negative realm!** which I guess is what you would actually like. But I think this is impossible!

So, I suggest you don't use the code below, unless you are OK with simply bringing the `PictureBox.Top` back to zero!

```
// a variable at class level:
VScrollBar vScroll = null;

// move into negative for testing:
pictureBox1.Top = -15;
// now check to see if we need a VScrollBar
scrollCheck();

void scrollCheck()
{
    if (pictureBox1.Top < 0)
    {
        if (vScroll == null )
        { vScroll = new VScrollBar(); vScroll.Parent = panel1.Parent;
        vScroll.Scroll += vScroll_Scroll; vScroll.BringToFront();
        }
        vScroll.Location = new Point(panel1.Right - vScroll.Width - 2, panel1.Top + 1);
        vScroll.Height = panel1.ClientSize.Height - 2;
        vScroll.Value = vScroll.Maximum;
        vScroll.Show();
        }
    else
    { vScroll.Hide(); }
}

void vScroll_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    int delta = e.NewValue - e.OldValue;
    if (delta < 0)
    {
        pictureBox1.Top = 0;
        scrollCheck();
    }
}
```

All in all I really believe that avoiding the situation will be best..

Comment: can u give me the link to learn using scrollbars and how to manipulate scrollbars according to another control (tutorials) ?

Comment: I have coded an example but I doubt that using it will be such a good idea..The controls in the negative left and upper regions will never show, whatever you do unless you move them back!